# Meaning and origin of "rally peters out"

Tags: meaning, nouns, phrasal-verbs

Positive reactions from stock markets can be described as the markets "rallying peters out". See [this guardian article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/business/2012/jul/31/eurozone-crisis-live-markets-await-ecb-action) for an example of this usage.

I don't quite understand this proverb. Where does it come from and how to interpret it? Is it linked to St. Peter for instance?

*EDIT: I edited the tags, as this is not about a proverb*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misunderstood. The headline "market rally peters out" means that the "market [rally](http://mw4.m-w.com/dictionary/rally%5b2%5d)" (the market's partial recovery) "[petered out](http://mw4.m-w.com/dictionary/peter)" (trailed off; gradually ended). In other words, the market went up briefly, but then it stopped. There is no proverb here.

Answer (score 4):

*To peter out* is a verb that means "to diminish gradually" or "to dwindle".

The etymology seems to be uncertain, and may be related to St Peter. [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/peter-out.html) traces the first use of the phrase to the Californian Gold Rush.